# Can't received inbound sms in plivo, it dosen't trigger codeigniter url

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, sms-gateway, plivo

Recently I'm trying to received sms to plivo number. when i sent a sms from outsite plivo then it sent and plivo log status will show delivered. But i need to save data into database. It does not trigger to my controller function.
I already sent sms through another function. it sent and saved into my database but problem is, when anyone reply into this number.

controller function:

```
 public function index()
{
    // Sender's phone numer
    $from_number = $this->input->get("From");  // $this->input->post("From"); dosen't work.
    // Receiver's phone number - Plivo number
    $to_number = $this->input->get("To"); // $this->input->post("To"); dosen't work.
    // The SMS text message which was received
    $text = $this->input->get("Text");  // $this->input->post("Text"); dosen't work.
    // Output the text which was received to the log file.
    // error_log("Message received - From: ".$from_number.", To: ".$to_number. ", Text: ".$text);
    $arr = array("from" => $from_number, "to" => $to_number, "text" => $text);
    $this->receive_model->add($arr);
}
```

Plivo application URL :
http://xxxxxxx.com/receive_sms

Message Method : GET

Message Method : POST // Dosen't work.

Codeigniter Config: 
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;

In plivo log status delivered.

any help?

Comment: If you solved it by yourself, please post the answer yourself. For others to see.

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: At the first time i load plivo library class on the sms received controller, it was a problem. I just erase those line from controller and then it works fine. ** We have to follow 1. Plivo application always get data for codeigniter function. 2. Codeigniter Config: `$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;`  3. SMS received controller only load Codeigniter library file, nothing else. **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first time i load plivo library class on the sms received controller, it was a problem. I just erase those line from controller and then it works fine.

We have to follow:

**Plivo application always get data for codeigniter function. Codeigniter Config: `$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;` SMS received controller only load Codeigniter library file, nothing else.**

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Plivo started their Stop DND protocol a few days ago (i.e. June 2016). When a message comes back in response to a text from a Plivo phone number that says Stop... all further messages from Plivo are blocked.

The Plivo number sends a message and the recipient responds with Stop.

There is no do over. From then on, NO messages from Plivo will be delivered to that recipient as the recipients Stop message is interpreted as a request that all further messages be blocked.

Plivo offers no way of turning message delivery back on. That user has no way of correcting the Stop if sent in error. There is no do over.

All solutions lead to using a new different phone number.

A band aid... Incoming messages to that Plivo number still get received so there is the possibility of sending outgoing response messages from a second Plivo or other number. In theory looks OK BUT in reality this is at best a short term fix.

Most users naturally depend on sending messages by replying. Replying to the wrong new incoming number, instead of sending to the original phone number, just sets up another set of problems and issues to deal with. Not the least of those is what ever reason that caused the stop message in the 1st place or accidentally doing it again. Ends up like cutting your finger off 1/16th of an inch at a time.